# Provoke a unhandled exception

Tags: c++, windows, exception

I want to test a bunch of "application crash dump generators" like good old [Dr. Watson](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2007/06/15/capturing-application-crash-dumps.aspx).

What is the easiest way to provoke an application crash over a unhandled exception in C/C++?

Comment: why dont you use [link](.....) format?

Comment: I didn't know about it and don't understand what it's good for. The link is already self-explanatory.

Comment: Not a big stuff. But large links seems bad to read

Comment: Unhandled C++ exception or unhandled Windows exception? The accepted answer does not generate a C++ exception, but does generate an OS exception on Windows. Yet the question is tagged C++, not Windows.

Comment: I looked for an unhandled OS exception.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While technically dereferencing a `NULL` pointer is simply an undefined behavior, not a guaranteed crash, in practice it would crash with nearly absolute certainty:

```
(*((int*)0))=0;
```

Comment: Way too many parentheses. `*(int*)0 = 0;` is sufficient. `<g>`