# How to generate an exception that could crash a site to test it

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Could someone help me with some code I could run in an .aspx page which I could put on a site to make it crash? I'd like to test if procdump works or not and this could be helpful for me.

something similar to:
[Provoke a unhandled exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14869977/provoke-a-unhandled-exception)

Comment: `void Test() { Test(); }` and then call somewhere as `Test();` - you definitely won't catch that one :-D

Comment: Have a function call itself recursively. `StackOverflowException` will occur and the process will crash.

Comment: What I want is an exception that would crash the w3wp process (the site) using an .aspx file that I add to the site and then access.

Comment: @Joe Try my or John's suggestions (they are the same thing).

Comment: thanks, tried Johns and it seems to work

Answer (score -1):

Directly inside the html portion of your page, you can add the following:

```
<div>
    @{throw new Exception(); }
</div>
```

When the page renders via the Razor engine, an exception will be thrown from within the page itself. You don't need to change the controller for such a simple test. For more debugging on the server-side, add it to your action in the controller so you can add a breakpoint. For instance,

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    throw new Exception();
    return View();
}
```